# Swiper not working in an Angular Ionic app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, swiper.js

So i'm trying to implement a slider in an angular application. I stumble upon SwiperJS which seems to do everything I need.
The first implementation works and I'm able to slide between images, but I also need sometimes to scroll to an image of the slider, and this does not work.

I'm using Swiper 9.4.1

It's registered in the AppComponent via this import:

```
import { register } from 'swiper/element/bundle';
register();
```

In the global.scss file

```
@import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.css';
```

Then I added the custom elements in my page's module

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
@NgModule({
    ...
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
})
export class ProductInfoPageModule {}
```

In my template, I added the swiper like this:

```
<swiper-container class="swiperContainer" #swiperContainer>
    <swiper-slide *ngFor="let img of selectedArticle.media_gallery">
        <img [src]="img | mainPhoto : product.brand" alt="'img'" />
    </pinch-zoom>
    </swiper-slide>
</swiper-container>
```

Finally, in the page I initialised it with a initSwiper() function, called after all the data have been collected:

```
@ViewChild('mainGrid') mainGrid: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('swiperContainer', { static: true }) swiperContainer: ElementRef;
[...]
public initSwiper(): void {
  this.swiper = new Swiper('.swiperContainer', {
    cssMode: true,
    speed: 400
  });
}
```

When the user click in the page, I want to be able to scroll the Swiper to the corresponding image:

```
public onThumbnailClick(index: number): void {
  this.thumbnailIndex = index;
  this.swiper.slideTo(index);
}
```

But when the code runs, it fires this error from the Swiper library:
*Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'scrollTo') at Swiper.slideTo (slideTo.js:112:17)*

The code that fires this error is here:

```
wrapperEl.scrollTo()
```

It looks like the "wrapperEl" is never initialized
How can I correct this?